# Ubuntu hadn't setup itself for booting

Tags: boot, windows-7

I have recently installed Ubuntu 15.05 on my laptop.
The problem is that I can't boot it anyway.

Win7 is the only loading OS. But it does not offer choosing an OS for me.
Also I can't see and access from windows explorer the disks, which where used to install Ubuntu. But I can see them in disk management as two primary disks, that Win7 see as other OS disks.

How do I add Linux to BCD to be choosen as OS, if I can't even access these disks?

However I can load Linux(ISO installation image) from my flash drive.
Here is the list of the disks as they are seen by linux and win7:

/dev/sda1 ≈100mb Windows 7(loader) Not seen in explorer

/dev/sda2 ≈100gb Windows 7(loader) Seen by win7 as system primary boot ...(etc) disk Windows.System(C).

/dev/sda5 ≈130gb Seen by win7 as logical disk Documents(D).

/dev/sda6 ≈70gb Set as "swap" on Ubuntu installing. Not seen in explorer. Seen by win7 as primary disk of other OS.

/dev/sda7 ≈94.58gb Seen by win7 as logical disk Programs(E).

/dev/sda8 ≈70gb Set as installation disk for Ubuntu, ext2. Not seen in explorer. Seen by win7 as primary disk of other OS.

Also I wan't to add, that these sizes, that written higher, are not the same, as Ubuntu displayed. These as sizes, as they are seen by win7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple disk you may have to change in your bios the default one to boot in.
The disk you have selected has only BCD (windows boot chain loader) so it uses that. Btw linux is not installed on windows bootchainloader, if you want to you can try to use EasyBCD (http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/easybcd.html) to edit this.

Otherwise you may try to select a different disk (the one you have installed linux on), so you will boot on grub2 winch has an automatically add entry named "Windows".

Comment: However I tried different settings, EasyBCD hasn't helped me. No entries booting linux.

Comment: This is logical, have you installed linux on a seprate hard drive, if this is the case you have to select it on the bios to boot on it. It will give you the possibility to boot on windows too.
Usually F8 let you select a drive to boot on.

Comment: My bios does not let me to select disk. Only a drive. When I choose hdd to boot only windows starts.

Comment: You may try to reinstall ubuntu or you may want to give a shot to wubi
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi